# Question about circles.

Tags: geometry

Find the value of x. If necessary, round your answer to the nearest tenth. The figure is not drawn to scale.

AB = 19, BC = 10, and CD = 5

[image: figure]

A)23

B)53

C)38

D)58

What theorem should I use? And how do I use that theorem?

Comment: AC*BC=CD*(CD+X)

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Secant_Secant_Theorem and http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Tangent_Secant_Theorem proves that if  you are curious

Comment: I got 47. What am I doing wrong?
24*10=5*(5+x) Is where I started.

Comment: 47 does not work in your equation... but the equation isn't set up right anyway.  What is the length of AC according to the given information? (It's _not_ 24.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AC = AB + BC = 19 + 10 = 29

if AC*BC=CD*(CD+X), then 29*10 = 5*(5+x)
290 + 25 + 5x
5x = 265
x = 53